# Safe way connect a 3.3V output to an input with weak pullup to 5V

Tags: output, beaglebone-black, 5v

I plan to connect a 5V IC to a beaglebone black(explicitly not  5V tolerant 3.3V IOs). For signals going to the beaglebone black I need a level shifter.

But the input of the 5V IC has a weak pullup to 5V. Datasheet says the pullup is 25kOhm nominal. Can I just connect an output pin from the beaglebone black to this input? I measured the current when shorting the pin to 3.3V as 53µA (Which seems plausible given the 25kOhm nominal)

For my application it's required in case the input is not driven by the beaglebone black it is still pulled up.

Comment: Does your beaglebone output support tri-state?

Comment: @MartinZabel: The pin's boot default is 'High-impedance with an active pulldown resistor' but the function i want to use doesn't support tri-state as far as i know. I think i would need a stronger pullup if i would use tri-state / drive low instead of push/pull. Hmm, maybe a additional pullup to 3.3V with reasonable strength would make this safe anyway?

Answer (score 1):

If you invert logic on the Beaglebone Black software control for the output, then a simple transistor will work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHIifX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Not sure if the 25kΩ resistor is internal or external to the 5V IC you are using, you didn't name it. If it's internal you don't need to include it.)

When the BBB GPIO is logic HIGH, the 5V input is logic LOW. The transistor is any common small signal transistor, R2's value is not particularly important (1kΩ - 30kΩ), and it needs a ground common to both the BBB and the 5V IC to work.

Comment: I my application i can't invert the signal because it's not an GPIO but a hardwired function (can). So this approch would either expand to two transistors or some other buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Your Beaglebone output probably has internal diodes between the output and its 3.3 V supply. When the BB drives a logic '1', its high side FET will be on, and you would expect to sink (5-3.3)/25k = 68 uA. When (if) the BB's output goes highZ, the pin will be pulled to 3.3+0.7 = 4.0 V by the 25k pull-up on the 5 V IC. This is probably out of spec, but probably OK for 'home' use. I expect the BB's output is actually specified at 3.6 V max.

Note that this 68 uA (or 53 uA) will then flow into the BB's 3.3 V VDD supply line. If the total current consumption of the BB is less than this, the 3.3 VDD supply will get pulled up.

If you are OK with wasting some current, you could add a 3.3 V zener in parallel with the BB's output, although the tolerances of these may not make the V exactly 3.3 V -- and if the zener is low, you will then have a concern about the 5 V IC reading a '1' correctly. A better alternative is to add a schottky between the BB's output and its 3.3VDD supply (assuming the total supply load is > 68 uA as above).

As far as reliability is concerned, the greatest stress on the outputs is when they are switching, and with a 25k pull-up, it is doubtful that your switching frequency is significantly high.

Note that for signals *from* the 5V IC to the BB, if you can configure those as weak pull-ups also, you can use the same technique, but the data will flow the other way.

Comment: Good point that i should have a look at what happens in sleep modes (BB running should take more during normal operation). Actually the normal operation will be usage of the output in push/pull mode with something around 125kHz. That 25k pullup is just one of the safety measures built in the other chip(can-phy). And you are right the absolute maximum ratings table has 3.6V for all IO pins.